# Remove fragment in URL with JavaScript w/out causing page reload

Tags: javascript, html, url, fragment-identifier

**Background:** I have an HTML page which lets you expand certain content. As only small portions of the page need to be loaded for such an expansion, it's done via JavaScript, and not by directing to a new URL/ HTML page. However, as a bonus the user is able to permalink to such expanded sections, i.e. send someone else a URL like

*http://example.com/#foobar*

and have the "foobar" category be opened immediately for that other user. This works using parent.location.hash = 'foobar', so that part is fine.

**Now the question:** When the user closes such a category on the page, I want to empty the URL fragment again, i.e. turn http://example.com/#foobar into http://example.com/ to update the permalink display. However, doing so using `parent.location.hash = ''` causes a reload of the whole page (in Firefox 3, for instance), which I'd like to avoid. Using `window.location.href = '/#'` won't trigger a page reload, but leaves the somewhat unpretty-looking "#" sign in the URL. So is there a way in popular browsers to JavaScript-remove a URL anchor including the "#" sign without triggering a page refresh?

Comment: This [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for) is an interesting read.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the hash from window.location (URL) with JavaScript without page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397329/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-window-location-url-with-javascript-without-page-r)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

As others have mentioned, [replaceState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_replaceState%28%29.C2.A0method) in HTML5 can be used to remove the URL fragment.

Here is an example:

```
// remove fragment as much as it can go without adding an entry in browser history:
window.location.replace("#");

// slice off the remaining '#' in HTML5:    
if (typeof window.history.replaceState == 'function') {
  history.replaceState({}, '', window.location.href.slice(0, -1));
}
```

Comment: Solid.  I appreciate the detection of ability to remove the #, but backwards compatible.

Comment: on spot answer. I am using this now

Comment: `history.replaceState` is great, but the `slice` is fragile. Have a look at the [Location interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) for alternatives.

Answer (score 14):

Since you are controlling the action on the hash value, why not just use a token that means "nothing", like "#_" or "#default".

Comment: I think this is an idea worthy of consideration.

Comment: Yes, you can also use a blank anchor, so then the URL ends up as being http://example.com/#. This is almost perfect, but I think it can also end up looking slightly confusing to some visitors. Ideally there whouldn't even be that hash character showing...

Comment: Obviously. Your scripts should function with nothing in the hash.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the shiny new HTML5 `window.history.pushState` and `replaceState` methods, as described in [ASCIIcasts 246: AJAX History State](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/246-ajax-history-state) and [on the GitHub blog](https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider). This lets you change the entire path (within the same origin host) not just the fragment. To try out this feature, [browse around a GitHub repository](https://github.com/chrisboyle/sgtpuzzles) with a recent browser.

Answer (score 2):

Put this code on head section.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var uri = window.location.toString();
    if (uri.indexOf("?") > 0) {
        var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("?"));
        window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_uri);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also another option instead of using hash, 
you could use `javascript: void(0);`
Example: `<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="open_div">Open Div</a>`

I guess it also depends on when you need that kind of link, so you better check the following links:

How to use it: http://www.brightcherry.co.uk/scribbles/2010/04/25/javascript-how-to-remove-the-trailing-hash-in-a-url/
or check debate on what is better here: [Which "href" value should I use for JavaScript links, "#" or "javascript:void(0)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0)

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".lnk").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).attr("href", "stripped_url_via_desired_regex");
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you Florin, could you please explain what this code does?

Answer (score -1):

So use

`parent.location.hash = ''` first

then do

```
window.location.href=window.location.href.slice(0, -1);
```

Comment: changing location.href in any way will reload the page.

Comment: That does work to get rid of the entire fragment including the '#' but Evgeny is right, it reloads the page

Answer (score -2):

As others have said, you can't do it. Plus... seriously, as the [jQuery Ajaxy](http://balupton.com/sandbox/jquery-ajaxy/demo/) author - I've deployed complete ajax websites for years now - and I can guarantee no end user has ever complained or perhaps ever even noticed that there is this hash thing going on, user's don't care as long as it works and their getting what they came for.

A proper solution though is HTML5 PushState/ReplaceState/PopState ;-) Which doesn't need the fragement-identifier anymore:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history
For a HTML5 and HTML4 compatible project that supports this HTML5 State Functionality check out https://github.com/browserstate/History.js :-)

Comment: There are better reasons to do that than "the user cares".  For example: https://wistia.com/blog/fresh-url