# How to remove the hash from window.location (URL) with JavaScript without page refresh?

Tags: javascript, window.location, fragment-identifier

I have URL like: `http://example.com#something`, how do I remove `#something`, without causing the page to refresh?

I attempted the following solution:

```
window.location.hash = '';
```

**However, this doesn't remove the hash symbol `#` from the URL.**

Comment: Do you really want to do this?  It'll cause a page refresh.

Comment: Is it possible to do without a page refresh?

Comment: It *is* possible. AJAX history libraries deal with it. But it's not easy, and it has to be done differently for almost every browser. Not something you wanna get into.

Comment: Is there any conciderations with leaving a "#" behind other than a visual one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Comment: and [Remove fragment in URL with JavaScript w/out causing page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/q/269044)

Answer (score 246, accepted):

**Initial question:**

```
window.location.href.substr(0, window.location.href.indexOf('#'))
```

or

```
window.location.href.split('#')[0]
```

both will return the URL without the hash or anything after it.

**With regards to your edit:**

Any change to `window.location` will trigger a page refresh. You can change `window.location.hash` without triggering the refresh (though the window will jump if your hash matches an id on the page), but you can't get rid of the hash sign. Take your pick for which is worse...

**MOST UP-TO-DATE ANSWER**

The right answer on how to do it without sacrificing (either full reload or leaving the hash sign there) is [up here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5298684/290343). Leaving this answer here though with respect to being the original one in 2009 whereas the correct one which leverages new browser APIs was given 1.5 years later.

Comment: This is just plain wrong, you can change window.location.hash and it will not trigger a refresh.

Comment: @Evgeny -- That's what my answer says. I explicitly say that changing window.location.hash won't trigger a refresh. "You can change window.location.hash without triggering the refresh (though the window will jump if your hash matches an id on the page)".

Comment: No page reload - that is in the question. This is not the answer as it requires/forces a page reload!

Comment: also think it should not be the ✓answer

Comment: @abernier Agreed, doesn't say how do to remove the hash from the URL, just the URL string.

Comment: If the href has a #, both the substr and split methods will work. But if the href has no #, the substr method returns empty string, while the split returns the href.

Comment: @LittleBigBot obviously just: window.location = window.location.href.split('#')[0]; ...

Comment: @smftre I think I meant that it doesn't specify how to remove the hash from `window.location`, but it just removes it from the string it returns.

Comment: This is not an answer to the OP question.

Comment: "Leaving this answer here though with respect to being the original one in 2009 whereas the correct one which leverages new browser APIs was given 1.5 years later."

The best answer should be at the top, not the first or whatever. This isn't about status. It's about getting the best information to people. Either edit this answer to include the better information or make the better information the accepted answer.

Comment: this is the correct answer and perfectly explained.

Comment: thanks for updating with the current answer later in the thread OP <3

Comment: @Evgeny `window.location.hash=""` will remove the hash id , but the hash at the end of the url will remain eg: `/index.html#id` becomes `/index.html#`

Comment: @dlaliberte if there is no delimeter in s string to split split() function will return the original string in an array not empty string eg: `"/index.html#id".split("#") // ["/index.html","id"]` and `"/index.html".split("#") // ["/index.html"]`

Answer (score 690):

Solving this problem is much more within reach nowadays.  The [HTML5 History API](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#the-history-interface) allows us to manipulate the location bar to display any URL within the current domain.

```
function removeHash () { 
    history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname
                                                       + window.location.search);
}
```

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/ycmPt/show/**

This works in Chrome 9, Firefox 4, Safari 5, Opera 11.50 *and* in IE 10.  For unsupported browsers, you could always write a gracefully degrading script that makes use of it where available:

```
function removeHash () { 
    var scrollV, scrollH, loc = window.location;
    if ("pushState" in history)
        history.pushState("", document.title, loc.pathname + loc.search);
    else {
        // Prevent scrolling by storing the page's current scroll offset
        scrollV = document.body.scrollTop;
        scrollH = document.body.scrollLeft;

        loc.hash = "";

        // Restore the scroll offset, should be flicker free
        document.body.scrollTop = scrollV;
        document.body.scrollLeft = scrollH;
    }
}
```

So you can get rid of the hash symbol, just not in all browsers — yet.

<sub>Note: if you want to replace the current page in the browser history, use `replaceState()` instead of `pushState()`.</sub>

Comment: Use this line to make sure you don't lose the query string: history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname + window.location.search);

Comment: @Phil: thanks for pointing that out, I've updated the answer accordingly.  I'm too used to using pretty URLs.

Comment: For older versions of IE, it seems you need to use document.documentElement instead of document.body. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2717272/359048

Comment: I suggest using replaceState instead of pushState, to not create an extra entry in the browser history.

Comment: Is there any difference between [location.hash=" ";] and  calling the suggested function [removeHash();]. becoz for me, both are giving the same error at console as : [Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!] Any suggestion ?

Comment: I think history.pushState will not trigger **hashshange** whereas window.location.hash will. To me this event is very important, so just be careful

Comment: @santiagoarizti: `history.pushState()` **will** trigger a *hashchange* event.  The fiddle in my answer demonstrates this by toggling the disabled state of a button in the *hashchange* event.

Comment: interesting, I made my own fiddle to demonstrate that it didn't work before I wrote a comment here... look: https://jsfiddle.net/k76qefn1/

Comment: ok, I inspected your fiddle and the "hashchange" event only triggers on the `href="#hash"` click, which is to be expected, but it doesn't trigger after `history.pushState` which is what I am warning people about

Comment: @santiagoarizti: you're right, I just came to the same conclusion. I didn't inspect the code I wrote (7 years ago!) properly and missed that I was also toggling the state of the button when removing the hash.  Since you are changing the hash manually, you could always trigger the event yourself, I suppose.

Comment: In (at least) Firefox 63, you will need a full URL (including domain name) to satisfy security checks. `history.replaceState('', document.title, window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + window.location.search);` Note addition of "window.location.origin". The answer, as given above, does not work in Chrome 70, but this modification does. Tested in Firefox 63, Chrome 70, IE 11, Edge.

Comment: OK, it seems that the problem was underspecified by the original poster, so I need to specify:
I need to have ABSOLUTE, AUTOCRATIC AND TYRANNICAL CONTROL over the following aspects of behavior INDEPENDENTLY:
1) the hash part of the URL in the location changing
2) the trailing # in the URL staying or being gone after `location.hash=""`
3) scrolling to the anchor
4) triggering of the hashchange event

No one who cannot offer a reliable implementation of `setHash(hash, shouldChangeLocationBar, shouldHashRemain, shouldScroll, shouldTriggerEvent)` can claim to have solved The Problem.

Comment: @Nico Your comment is very helpful for at time of back button because I don't want to back path with #string. Thank for my time-saving.

Answer (score 165):

(Too  many answers are redundant and outdated.) The best solution now is this:

```
history.replaceState(null, null, ' ');
```

Comment: use `history.pushState(null, null, ' ')` instead if you want to preserve history.

Comment: It might be useful to explain what passing `null` for the `state` and `title` parameters ultimately does.

Comment: A problem with this, and the rest, is that it doesn't trigger onhashchange, even though the hash is now empty when it wasn't before.

Comment: In TypeScript, null is not allowed for the second parameter because the command takes a string. Mozilla recommends empty string.

Comment: is this behavior documented somewhere? is it supported by all browsers/versions?

Comment: That is the right answear.

Comment: @Curtis null! should work as a "hack"

Comment: Also why does `' '` for url result in same page without hash? whereas e.g. `'hello'` replaces the last fragment of the url, and `''` does nothing. Is this documented somewhere? How reliably is it?

Answer (score 52):

Simple and elegant:

```
history.replaceState({}, document.title, ".");  // replace / with . to keep url
```

Comment: use a dot instead of a slash if you want to stay in the same directory

Comment: Please update answer as regards @vahanpwns note, to use `.` instead of `/`. Using `/` changes the url to the root path.

Comment: I've updated the answer for a better explanation of what's going on in the example

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I modified to `history.replaceState({}, document.title, location.href.substr(0, location.href.length-location.hash.length));` for my use case.

Comment: This does not preserve url query.

Comment: My use-case was also to replace instead of push, but this makes more sense to me: `history.replaceState(null, document.title, location.pathname + location.search);`

Answer (score 32):

You can do it as below:

```
history.replaceState({}, document.title, window.location.href.split('#')[0]);
```

Comment: The starred answer didn't work for me in either case, but this one did. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

This will remove the trailing hash as well. 
eg: http://test.com/123#abc -> http://test.com/123

```
if(window.history.pushState) {
    window.history.pushState('', '/', window.location.pathname)
} else {
    window.location.hash = '';
}
```

Comment: This removes any query params present in the URL :(

Comment: @kevgathuku you can add them back with location.search, eg: ` window.history.pushState('', '/', window.location.pathname + window.location.search)`

Answer (score 15):

To remove the hash, you may try using this function

```
function remove_hash_from_url()
{
    var uri = window.location.toString();
    if (uri.indexOf("#") > 0) {
        var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("#"));
        window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_uri);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

How about the following?

`window.location.hash=' '`

Please note that am setting the hash to a single space and not an empty string.

---

Setting the hash to an invalid anchor does not cause a refresh either. Such as,

`window.location.hash='invalidtag'`

But, I find above solution to be misleading. This seems to indicate that there is an anchor on the given position with the given name although there isn't one. At the same time, using an empty string causes page to move to the top which can be unacceptable at times. Using a space also ensures that whenever the URL is copied and bookmarked and visited again, the page will usually be at the top and the space will be ignored.

And, hey, this is my first answer on StackOverflow. Hope someone finds it useful and it matches the community standards.

Comment: Setting hash to whitespace still keeps the # at the end of the URL, I think the goal is to remove it altogether.

Comment: It trails a hash at the end of the URL. The question is how to remove that.

Comment: Yes how can we can remove # as well with hash string.

Comment: Even with something like `document.location.hash = "avalidtagthatdoesntconfusejavascriptanditsanexampleafterall"` it still makes it `#avalidtagthatdoesntconfusejavascriptanditsanexampleafterall`

Answer (score 6):

```
const url = new URL(window.location);
url.hash = '';
history.replaceState(null, document.title, url);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 5):

```
function removeLocationHash(){
    var noHashURL = window.location.href.replace(/#.*$/, '');
    window.history.replaceState('', document.title, noHashURL) 
}

window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    removeLocationHash();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var uri = window.location.toString();
if (uri.indexOf("?") > 0) {
    var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("?"));
    window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_uri);
}
</script>
```

put this code on head section

Answer (score 3):

I think, it would be more safe

```
if (window.history) {
    window.history.pushState('', document.title, window.location.href.replace(window.location.hash, ''));
} else {
    window.location.hash = '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (window.location.href.includes('#')) {
    const cleanedUrl = window.location.href.split('#')[0];
    window.history.replaceState(null, null, cleanedUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
window.history.back(1);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question if the user has come directly to the URL including the hash.

Comment: This trick is very useful when you just want create a link to  previous page, but the link is hidden in bunch of js files.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. This works perfectly to remove a hashtag  just created by my web app in order to consume a value returned by a javasript function.

Comment: Well what if `<a href="#"></a>`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution to change the location using href and clear the hash without scrolling.

The magic solution is explained [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/09/history-api-scroll-restoration). Specs [here](https://majido.github.io/scroll-restoration-proposal/history-based-api.html#web-idl).

```
const hash = window.location.hash;
history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';
window.location.href = hash;    
history.pushState('', document.title, window.location.pathname);
```

NOTE: The proposed API is now part of WhatWG HTML Living Standard

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function (e) {
    history.replaceState('', document.title, e.oldURL);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off one of the answers given above, use this:

```
var scrollV, scrollH
var loc = window.location;
scrollV = document.body.scrollTop;
scrollH = document.body.scrollLeft;
if ("pushState" in history) {
    history.pushState("", document.title, loc.pathname + loc.search);

    // Restore the scroll offset
    document.body.scrollTop = scrollV;
    document.body.scrollLeft = scrollH;

} else {
    loc.hash = "";

    // Restore the scroll offset
    document.body.scrollTop = scrollV;
    document.body.scrollLeft = scrollH;
}
```

Answer (score -5):

You can replace hash with null

```
var urlWithoutHash = document.location.href.replace(location.hash , "" );
```

Comment: The question asks "without causing the page to refresh", but this method does refresh the page. You should note this fact in your answer, so we don't all have to waste our time finding out firsthand that you're answering a different question than the one we're actually trying to get answered here.

Comment: It does not refresh the page.

Comment: It does not refresh the page because it isn't updating the URL. `replace` returns a fresh new string and `location.href` remains the same. As soon as you do `location.href = urlWithouthHash` you will get the refresh.