# How to get «onclick» event through a transparent image?

Tags: javascript, html, image, events

I have a html page. In the middle of the page I show a gif-image which is partly transparent.

If I click on tranparent parts of the image on links which are under the image I do not get «onclick» event because of the image.

Is it possible to ignore image and get events on the links?

**UPDATE:** My layout: It is not possible to click on "Alternativ".

[image]

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Click through a DIV to underlying elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements) **or** [Ignore mouse interaction on transparent parts in image and assign it to the image below](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2607162/94197)

Answer (score 1):

Well if the links are *under* the image, then they are unclickable.

What you might need to do is **decrease** the css `z-index` of the image, and **increase** the `z-index` of the links to make them clickable.

Comment: Than the text will be over the image. It will does not help.

Answer (score 0):

If the image is static and not moving you can easily use image [maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/map) or put your links on top of the transparent image.

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't know your layout, but I think, there are several possibilities. You could use an imagemap to simulate a click on the links under the gif. So, where the link is positioned you define a clickable area in the image map. 
Anothe possibility would be to use the gif as background image. Shouldn't change anything in the layout and the links would be on top.

HTH,

--hennson

Answer (score 0):

Make an event, fire it off:

```
var realTarget = document.querySelector('...');
var img = document.querySelector('...');

img.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  var newEvt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  newEvt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
    evt.detail, evt.screenX, evt.screenY, evt.clientX, evt.clientY, 
    evt.ctrlKey, evt.altKey, evt.shiftKey, evt.metaKey, 
    evt.button, evt.relatedTarget);
  realTarget.dispatchEvent(newEvt);
}, false);
```