# Removing # from fragment identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to remove the '#' from the url after removing the fragment identifier.

For example:

```
var myUrl = location.href; // example.com/#abc
alert(location.hash);      // #abc
location.hash = ''; 
alert(myUrl);              // example.com/#
```

Now i try to remove the # WITHOUT a page reload. I tried to use the replace function but when i try to remove the '#' the page will reload. Is there a solution to solve this ?

Comment: I don't think so...  if you change the location object in any way (including assigning the same value as it already has) I believe the browser will always reload based on those changes.  I might be wrong (hense a comment rather than an answer), but that's my understanding

Comment: It can't be done. Altering the uri in the browser presents a security vulnerability. (phishing)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352343/changing-browsers-address-bar-without-refreshing

Comment: A hashtag is a means to flag a keyword for searching on twitter. I've removed your references to them.

Answer (score 0):

You should use HTML5 History API for this: http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html
You won't be using hashes anymore, but you can still load pages without reloading.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this questions:

- [How to remove the hash from window.location with JavaScript without
  page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397329/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-window-location-with-javascript-without-page-refresh)
- [Remove hash from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508574/remove-hash-from-url)