# node express res.redirect without hash

Tags: node.js, express

The page url is `http://example.com/dashboard#/catalog`. When the cookie expires, I do a

```
res.redirect('/login')
```

And the resulting url in the browser is `http://example.com/login#/catalog`.

How could I redirect without the hash part i.e Make the url to be `http://example.com/login`

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: which libraries are you using client-side? History.js or something like that?

Comment: you could always clear your hash on your login page... `window.location.hash=''`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are doing the logout part, but assuming you're using a link tag you could do something like this

```
$("a#logout").on('click', function() {
  // the following was taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508574/remove-hash-from-url
  var loc = window.location.href,
      index = loc.indexOf('#');
  if (index > 0) {
     window.location = loc.substring(0, index);
  }
});
```