# Remove hash from current page’s URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I want to remove the hash, as well as anything after it, from a URL. For example, I might have:

```
http://example.com/#question_1
```

… which slides to question no. 1 to show an error message. When the user’s input then passes validation, I need to remove `#question_1` from the current location.

I’ve tried all of these, but none of them has worked for me:

- `document.location.href.replace(location.hash, "");`
- `window.location.hash.split('#')[0];`
- `window.location.hash.substr(0, window.location.hash.indexOf('#'));`

Note: I don’t just want to get the URL – I want to remove it from my address bar.

Comment: What is `http://example.com#question_1`? currently loaded url?

Comment: See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508574/remove-hash-from-url

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the hash from window.location with JavaScript without page refresh?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397329/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-window-location-with-javascript-without-page-refresh)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.href.replace(/\#(.+)/, '').replace(/http(s?)\:\/\/([^\/]+)/, '') )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :use `.split()` to split string by `#` and then read first element in array using index `0`

```js
    var url = 'http://example.com#question_1';
    var urlWithoutHash = url.split('#')[0];
    alert(urlWithoutHash );
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but i don't want to get URL, i just want to remove it from my URL bar

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` in javascript

```js
    var str = "http://example.com#question_1";
    
    alert(str.split("#")[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but i don't want to get URL, i just want to remove it from my URL ba

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
var currentPath = window.location.pathname;
var myUrl = currentPath.split("#")[0];
```

**OR**

```
var currentPath = window.location.href;
var myUrl = currentPath.split("#")[0];
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This will clear the id selector from the uri

```
location.hash = '';
```

Comment: You can't get rid of the hash without reloading the page I think this would be the closest to actually remove it from the address bar :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.split` as shown :

```
var str = "http://example.com#question_1";

alert((str.split("#")[0]);
```

or use `.substring()` as shown :

```
var str = "http://example.com#question_1";

alert((str.substring(0,str.indexOf('#'))));
```