# Remove what is after hash

Tags: jquery, url, hash

I have urls like:

```
http://stackoverflow.com#tab1
http://stackoverflow.com/something#tab1#tab3
http://stackoverflow.com/links.html#tab2#tab1#tab4
```

How can I remove everything after the hash sign, so I can keep a simple URL like:

```
http://stackoverflow.com
http://stackoverflow.com/something
http://stackoverflow.com/links.html
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here is your [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508574/remove-hash-from-url)

Comment: Thanks man, working greats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply use `.split()` the string and get the first object

```
var url = "http://stackoverflow.com/something#tab1#tab3";

console.log(url.split("#")[0]);
```

Dynamic url

```
console.log(window.location.href.split("#")[0]);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/voazL4cn/2/)