# Remove hash from (window.location.hash)

Tags: javascript, php, hash

I'm using this code

```
$("#reset_filter").on("click", function(e) {
    window.location.hash = "";
    window.location.reload();
});
```

for reset the URL on the page but because of (window.location.hash) on the end of the URL I always get `#`. Is it possible somehow to remove the `hash` from the URL? I already have tried with

```
window.location.href.substr(0, window.location.href.indexOf('#'))
```

and

```
window.location.href.split('#')[0]
```

but it was not working, any proposition and help please.

Comment: @Jordan it looks like artur has tested the answer given to that post, check his question.

Comment: Yes I already have tested this answer but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Read the answer under "With regards to your edit." The given code works if you assign the result to `window.location`, but it triggers a page refresh, hence the addendum. Also read the second-ranked answer. It may not solve artur's problem, but it gives the only correct answer (though I'd love to be proven wrong), and this question is still a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

No.  If you explicitly tell javascript to set a hash-location there will be a hash in the location.

Answer (score 0):

you can just make the page reload or you use

[Remove hash from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508574/remove-hash-from-url)

this:

> < a href='#anchor' onclick='return anchorJump(this.href)'>click

or

http://ajaxian.com/archives/ajax-tackle-the-refresh-button

but anyway what browser do you use?