# Replace URL without redirect

Tags: javascript, html

Remove the hash # from url (without redirect)

```
location.hash = "?userid=" + document.getElementById("userid").innerHTML;
location.href.replace('#', '');
```

EDIT: Answer = window.history.pushState("", "", window.location.href +  "?userid=" + document.getElementById("userid").innerHTML);

Comment: .replace() returns the adjusted string. So at the very least, you would need to do something like `location.href = location.href.replace( '#', '' );`

Comment: I had tried that already but it send it int an infinite loop

Comment: What?? What infinite loop?

Comment: simply `if(location.href.indexOf('?userid='==-1) location.href += "?userid=" + document.getElementById("userid").innerHTML`

Comment: Thank you i will try this now

Comment: If you're just trying to redirect to another page, it makes no sense to first add the hash with `location.hash` and then trying to remove it.

Comment: im not trying to redirect

Comment: im just trying to add to the end of the url for affiliate reasons

Comment: You can't add stuff to the URL without redirecting using this method.

Comment: Well can you help me, i tried substr(1) on the location hash but that didnt work.

Comment: @Juhana :  as  per her code it will continuously redirect the page, since script executes on page load

Comment: @PranavCBalan Of course it does. That's what I've been saying. Did you reply to the wrong person? (Brigitte is a female name, btw.)

Comment: @Brigitte Google for "change url without redirect".

Comment: Thanks all, please take back your down votes :( window.history.pushState("", "", window.location.href +  "?userid=" + document.getElementById("userid").innerHTML);

Comment: @PranavCBalan How are they not duplicates? [Replace method doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1433212/1529630) explains why `replace` without assignment does nothing. And [Remove hash from url](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4508574/1529630) explains how to achieve what the OP wants. Her answer here is a corollary of the top answer in there.

Answer (score 2):

```
window.history.pushState("", "", window.location.href +  "?userid=" + document.getElementById("userid").innerHTML);
```

Comment: Thanks dude :D  i appreciate it