# How to rewrite a path with a '#' sign in nginx

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-location

I have a path of the format `www.example.com/aaa` and `www.example.com/aaa#bbb` and I want to redirect it to `www.example.com`

I tried:

```
if ($uri ~ ^/(.*)(#.*)?) {
    rewrite ^/(.*)(#.*)? / permanent;
}
```

I even tried #. It seems to go inside if block. It replaces the first part, but the second part is appended to url. The new url becomes like `www.example.com/#bbb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hash in a URL (the portion of the URL following the `#`) is not sent in the HTTP request by design. Therefore, nginx can't do anything about it. When a user visits `http://example.com/#aaa`, nginx only sees a request for `http://example.com`

One potential workaround is to use Javascript on the front-end to remove the hash from the URL. Another Stack Overflow question describes how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4508751/3474615

Comment: Thanks mate, that link was really helpful.