# How to replace hash in url

Tags: javascript

How to replace a url like this

```
http://test.com/#part1
```

to:

```
http://test.com/part1
```

I know location.hash but it will detect if there is a hash in url.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the hash from window.location (URL) with JavaScript without page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397329/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-window-location-url-with-javascript-without-page-r)

Answer (score 7):

```
location.href = location.href.replace(location.hash,location.hash.substr(1))
```

Comment: Very helpful - I had a different question than OP - this answer helped

Answer (score 1):

You can use replace()

Here's a broken down version using `windows.location`:

```
var new_url = window.location.protocol + '//'
            + window.location.hostname + '/'
            + window.location.pathname + '/'
            + window.location.hash.replace('#','','g') ;
```

Or remove all the hashes:

```
var new_url = (window.location + '').replace('#','','g');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var file = location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 2);
var location = window.origin + "file";
window.location = location;
```

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion is using regex replace on string best and cleanest solution

```
.replace( /#.*/, "");
```

example

```
location.href = location.href.replace( /#.*/, "");
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of the original answer published 7 years ago. You should improve this or delete it since it adds no value as it is.