# Is it possible to have anchor on click follow the link but not place the "#text" on the url address?

Tags: jquery, anchor

I have something like this:

```
<a name="position">Position</a>

<a href="#position">Go to target position</a>
```

By using jquery, is it possible by some way, when clicking the anchor it follows the link but NOT place the "#position" on the URL address?

I tried `e.preventDefault()` on clicking the anchor, but that stops following the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see if this works:
http://jsfiddle.net/uzpcV/25/

extracting the "#id"
scrolling to that location
then canceling our the original click functionality

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function addClick(anchor,theUrl,i){
     anchor.click(function() {
            var whereToGo = theUrl.substr(theLocation);

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(eval('"' + whereToGo + '"')).offset().top
            }, 333);

            //hold it right there  
            return false;

        });
}

var allTheLinks = $("a");
var linksLength = allTheLinks.length;

//go through all the links   
for (var i = 0; i < linksLength; i++) {

    var theLink = allTheLinks.eq(i);
    var theUrl = theLink.attr("href");
    var theLocation = theUrl.indexOf("#");


    //check for #
    if (theLocation > -1) {
       addClick(theLink,theUrl,i)
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this has been addressed before:

[How to remove the hash from window.location with JavaScript without page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397329/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-window-location-with-javascript-without-page-refresh) The only difference would be that you would have to do window.location.href = (whatever the above resulted in).

Comment: What I want is this: (1) Clicking anchor takes user to target link (2) Since the target link on same page, no page refreshing is needed (3) I don't want to print #text on the URL address

Comment: Ya I totally get it. /:  see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page