# Turn the tab active based on the current url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have some list items in the "#registration_form_list" list. The default active list item is the list item with id "#generalInfo". But I want that when a url like
this "http://proj.test/user/profile?user=1#myTickets" is accessed the tab that stays active is the "My Tickets" tab.

So I want to turn the tab active based on the current url. But its not working with the jQuery below.

Do you know why?

Html:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills bg-light-gray registration_form_list" role="tablist">
    <li class="">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#generalInfo" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">
            <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="d-none d-lg-inline-block">General Info</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="disabled">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#myTickets" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span
                    class="d-none d-lg-inline-block">My Tickets</span></a>
    </li>
    <!-- more list items -->
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
   var path = window.location.href;

        $('.registration_form_list a').each(function () {
            var hash = $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];
            //alert(hash); appaers
            if (this.href === path) {
                // alert('test'); dont appears
                $('.registration_form_list a').removeClass('active');
                $('a[href="#'+hash+'"]').addClass('active');
            }
        });
```

For example I have a method where the user is redirected to the "http://proj.test/user/profile?user=1#myTickets" but the tab that remains active is the "#generalInfo" when the user accesses the page.

```
return redirect(route('user.index', ['user' => Auth::id()]).'#myTickets');
```

The tabs content are inside tab-content with the corresponding id like:

```
<div class="tab-content registration_body bg-white" id="myTabContent">

    <div class="tab-pane fade show active clearfix" id="generalInfo" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
    <!-- #generalInfo content -->
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane clearfix fade" id="myTickets" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
        <!-- #myTickets content -->
    </div>
    <!-- other tabs -->
</div>
```

Comment: Is that the full JavaScript code? Is the code in a `.ready()` handler?

Comment: Thanks, yes. The alert(hash); appears but an alert inside "if (this.href === path)" like: "
                if (this.href === path) {
                    alert('test');..." dont appears.

Comment: what value are you passing into `this.href`??

Comment: If you switch `this.href === path` for `hash === window.location.hash.replace('#', '')` does the second alert fire?

Comment: @joW you might want to have a look at this more general solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131273/twitter-bootstrap-tabs-url-doesnt-change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Obtain hash value from the url
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  // Try to find a nav-link with the hash
  var hashNavLink = $('.nav-link[href="'+hash+'"]');

  // If there is no link with the hash, take default link
  if (hashNavLink.length === 0) {
    hashNavLink = $('.nav-link[href="#generalInfo"]');
  }

  hashNavLink.addClass('active');
});
```

In this case you can be sure that if a wrong hash is in the url, the `#generalInfo` link will be set as active and in other cases the correct link will be always active.

You can obtain `hash` value directly from [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location).

Comment: If he were to use this code, he would need to remove the `active` class from the `#generalInfo` link in the HTML, otherwise multiple links could have the active class. Otherwise this is a good answer.

Comment: Thanks, but there is an issue. When the user is redirected to "proj.test/user/profile?user=1#myTickets"; the tab "My Tickets" stay active, but the tab content of the "My Tickets" don't appear. It still appears the tab content of the "#generalInfo"

Comment: Just add `hashNavLink.tab('show')` after `hashNavLink.addClass('active');` It should help

Answer (score 1):

`var path = window.location.href;` returns the entire path of your URL.

`this.href` is equaling `#generalInfo` so it will never equal `http://proj.test/user/profile?user=1#generalInfo`

If you want to have a condition on the URL vs the href value of your anchor tag, you need to cut down your `path`

```
//This will always assume you're only using 1 pound sign    
var path = window.location.href.split("#")[1];
```

This way, `path` = `generalInfo` (assuming you're on http://proj.test/user/profile?user=1#generalInfo)

Then you need to make your condition `if(hash === path){}` (not `if (this.href === path)` because this.href is equal to `#generalInfo` and not just `generalInfo`

So it would now be looking for `generalInfo === generalInfo`

Whole code would be:

```
 var path = window.location.href.split('#')[1]; //equals the hash

    $('.registration_form_list a').each(function () {
        var hash = $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];
        //alert(hash); appaers
        if (hash === path) {
            // alert('test'); dont appears
            $('.registration_form_list a').removeClass('active');
            $('a[href="#'+hash+'"]').addClass('active');
        }
    });
```

(as a side note, something I like to do is remove the `active` class off of *all* anchor links in this situation before you add a new one to the specific one)

Comment: Thanks, but there is an issue. When the user is redirected to "proj.test/user/profile?user=1#myTickets"; the tab "My Tickets" stay active, but the tab content of the "My Tickets" don't appear. It still appears the tab content of the "#generalInfo"

Comment: @johnW Based on your comment, you may need to either update your question or start a new one.  The question as read when answering was asking how to make the *tab* active.  We'll have to see your HTML to know where the actual content is to show that