# Difference between empty hash and no hash

Tags: jquery, anchor

Using jQuery, is there a way to distinguish between no hash and an empty hash on the current `window.location` ?

This is what I call an "empty hash":

```
http://domain.tld/#
```

And this is "no hash":

```
http://domain.tld/
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`window.location.hash` will return `""` for both no hash and empty hash.  If you need to make a distinction for some reason, you could split `window.location.href` by `#`:

```
var frag = window.location.href.split("#");

if (frag.length == 1) {
    // No hash
}
else if (!frag[1].length) {
    // Empty hash
}
else {
    // Non-empty hash
}
```

Or checking for existing hash first, as per your request:

```
if (window.location.hash) {
    // Non-empty hash
}
else if (window.location.href.split("#").length == 1) {
    // No hash
}
else {
    // Empty hash
}
```

See also: [How to remove the hash from window.location with JavaScript without page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397329/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-window-location-with-javascript-without-page-refresh/5298684#5298684)

Comment: Is there a way to write it like so: if (the hash is not empty) {} elseif (there is no hash) {} else { // empty hash } ?

Comment: @bobylapointe: Sure, though it doesn't make a lot of difference since only one block would be executed each time.  See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery for this. If you have an empty hash, then all you need to do is check the last character of `window.location.href`. The following will return `true` if there is an empty hash:

```
window.location.href.lastIndexOf('#') === window.location.href.length - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested in a reusable version of Andy E's solution. I made a simple function to get the actual hash-state, as bitwise value.

```
/**
 * Checks if the location hash is given, empty or not-empty.
 *
 * @param {String} [href] Url to match against, if not given use the current one
 * @returns {Number} An integer to compare with bitwise-operator & (AND)
 */
function getHashState(href) {
  var frag = (href || window.location.href).split('#');
  return frag.length == 1 ? 1 : !frag[1].length ? 2 : 4;
}
```

You can compare the return values easily with the bitwise AND-operator (`&`).

```
if (getHashState() & 1); // no hash
if (getHashState() & 2); // empty hash
if (getHashState() & 4); // no empty hash
```