# On page refresh show only site URL not extra added text in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, hyperlink

How can I remove internal link from the URL in my browser so when user refresh website he can see default URL?

For example:

**URL:** `www.something.com  //default website url`

after using internal links URL takes this form:

**URL:** `www.something.com/#top`

When I click refresh on my browser I am still seeing

**URL:** `www.something.com/#top` and I want to see **URL:** `www.something.com`

because on my iPad this is triggering two server calls and I need to be sure to remove those internal links.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The URL, including the hash (`#top`) represents a certain state on your website. If the user chooses to reload the page, they should be returned to that exact same state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to reset the hash on load if it was set before, keep in mind that this removes the ability to get to a certain hash by calling it directly.

```
window.onload = function(){
    window.location.hash = '';
}
```

Comment: but I can still use internal links? I just can't call it directly in the URL?

Comment: exactly. maybe there is a smarter way though

Comment: it's not working...I have just test it...I keep getting for example `www.something.com/#` I need to get `www.something.com`

Comment: I would argue that the empty hash is semantically the same as no #.
However the answer for that is provided in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397329/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-window-location-with-javascript-without-page-refresh