# twitter web intent callbacks do not fire in all versions of internet explorer when a hash exists in the URL

Tags: twitter, webintents

In all versions of IE, the web intent for tweet or follow are not firing when the url contains a hash. Here is an example:

This fails:

http://clientqa.rtm.com/impossiblycomfortable/test.html#abc

This works:

http://clientqa.rtm.com/impossiblycomfortable/test.html

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could get rid of the hash using Javascript with `window.location.hash`. (See [How to remove the hash from window.location with JavaScript without page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397329/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-window-location-with-javascript-without-page-refresh)). Is that what you were asking?

Comment: No, it's a bug. I don't want to remove the hashtag. All I'm saying is that if a url has a hashtag the twitter intent callback does not fire in any version of IE.