# Cut the "#div" part in the visible url

Tags: javascript, menu, hyperlink

I have a onepage block website. Main menu is a group of links leading to specific divs on the page. I would like the adress to stay the same. Links are like "mywebsite.com/#div1" etc., but after clicking it I would like the adress to stay in "mywebsite.com" form. Can you help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the hash from window.location with JavaScript without page refresh?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397329/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-window-location-with-javascript-without-page-refresh)