# Jquery/Javascript Remove # from address bar without refreshing page

Tags: jquery

I want to remove # from browser url without reloading the page. I've tried below one but no use

window.location.hash = "";
ex:
localhost:5000/en-us/sample/abc#/zxy

[How to remove the hash from window.location with JavaScript without page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397329/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-window-location-with-javascript-without-page-refresh)

Above answer doesn't work for me.

any help?

Comment: why do you want to do it... and how is `#` coming in the address bar

Comment: @Deryck: Uh? The hash is not even sent to the server.

Comment: The answer your referenced **is** the answer.  "You can change window.location.hash without triggering the refresh..., but you can't get rid of the hash sign."

Comment: Why? Just ignore it....