# How to call a function written in Snippet after redirecting the current window to a link (eg. window.location = "https://google.com")

Tags: javascript, code-snippets

```
this.testing = function(link) {
        window.location = link;
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            alert("It's loaded!");
        });
        //OR
        myFunctionCall()
    }
```

This is the code I'm trying to implement but after the window is redirected to a link Im not getting the alert.

> My aim is to call a function which is dependent on the window after getting redirected

Comment: This will resolve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21875390/redirect-page-and-call-javascript-function

Comment: @AbuSufian Yes this does work when written on javascript files. But while writing it in snippets as soon as a wondow is getting redirected to new link next steps in the code are not getting executed