# How to remove hash from the url after the link was followed?

Tags: jquery, url, hash

I'm looking for a way of removing the `url.com/index.html#content`. So I'm looking for a way to remove the `#content` part (posibly with jQuery?). Is there any way to achieve this ***after*** I've already clicked on the link?

Comment: Do you want to consume the URL in your code or do you want the browser address bar URL changed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397329/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-window-location-with-javascript-without-page-refresh

Comment: Yeah but the hash redirects to an element with the `id="content"` so first I don't know where to put this script (`<head>` section maybe?). Anyway more detailed example than just a link to a random question won't help me. Could I have an example of the whole code? If yes I'll mark it as answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway here's the solution I've found:

***HTML Markup:***

```
<a href='#content' onclick="return anchorJump('content')">Skip to Content</a>
```

***And here's the JavaScript:***

```
    function anchorJump( anchor )
{
  var targAnchor=null, anchorID=anchor.replace(/.*#([^\?]+).*/,'$1');   

  if( !(targAnchor=document.getElementById( anchorID )) )
   for(var i=0, found=false, da=document.anchors, len=da.length; i<len && !targAnchor; i++)
    targAnchor = (da[i].name==anchorID ? da[i] : null); 

  if(targAnchor)  
  {
   disp=getElemOffset(targAnchor);
   window.scrollTo(disp.x, disp.y);
  }
  else
   alert('Did not find anchor/element "'+anchorID+'"');

  function getElemOffset(elem)
  {
   var left = !!elem.offsetLeft ? elem.offsetLeft : 0;
   var top = !!elem.offsetTop ? elem.offsetTop : 0;

   while((elem = elem.offsetParent))
   { 
    left += !!elem.offsetLeft ? elem.offsetLeft : 0;
    top += !!elem.offsetTop ? elem.offsetTop : 0;
   }

   return {x:left, y:top};  
  }

 return false; 
}
```