# how to clean window.location.hash?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a side with a big number of parameters, like www.hello.com/kaleidoskop.html#look/2

If you reload this side you will still have the parameters.

I would like to delete them and start after refresh with www.hello.com/kaleidoskop.html

For this i made the following:

```
        function updateHash (t, clean) {
        if (clean) {
            var r = window.location.href.replace(/(javascript:|#).*$/, '');
            window.location.replace(r + '#' + t)
        } else window.location.hash = '#' + t
    }
```

But here I still have the #.

If I use `window.location.replace(r) or window.location.hash = r`
it loops.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: window.location.href.split('#')[0]; and var r = window.location.href.replace(/(javascript:|#).*$/, '');     do not work

Comment: no one of the mentioned (posted) answer is working for me.

Comment: Fixed my answer, should work now.

Comment: @hamburger take a look at AndyE's answer (2nd answer). It _should_ work

Comment: history is not a solution, because I change the parameters on scrolling and on refresh I would start again.

Comment: I don't see a reason you can't use that method in page head so that it removes hash value as soon as page starts loading.
Probably I'm missing something. Can you include your usecase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For newer browsers supporting the [HTML5 History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history):

```
history.pushState(null, null, location.pathname + location.search);
```

For older browsers (best you can do without reloading - still keeps the `#`):

```
window.location.hash = '';
```

Comment: are you trying to quote andy from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397329/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-window-location-with-javascript-without-page-refresh ?

Comment: @Ejay What are your trying to say, that I copy & pasted my answer? I didn't even read that before, my apologies for having the same idea as someone else.

Comment: no you did not copy, that's not what I am saying :) Since SO tries to reduce duplicate questions, it is better to mark a question duplicate if it can be.

Comment: sorry for me is this a different answer than Andy E has.
It works. thx jgillich