# Remove URL hash (not as variable) for hashchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

I'm working with jQuery `hashchange` event, and every button in my page uses this code like a link to another page:

```
window.location.hash = '#anotherpage';
```

When I need to go back to the homepage, `location.hash` leaves the hash character (#) in my URL, even with `location.hash = null` or `location.hash = ""`

Does anyone here know how can I remove the hash in this case?

EDIT:

As Dsafds and Daniel said, only go back to my home page can be easy if I use `window.location.hash = "#"`. The problem is the character (#) in the home page link, used for the other pages, like #contact, is normal, but my home page have the hash too (site.com/#). I need to remove it. Any other idea? Thanks!

Comment: what about `location.hash = '#'`

Comment: Thanks, Daniel! The hash is there with this new code too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the hash from window.location (URL) with JavaScript without page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397329/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-window-location-url-with-javascript-without-page-r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use this to go back to the home page:

```
window.location.hash="/" || window.location.hash="/home"
```

In your case:

```
window.location.hash = "#"
```

### EDIT

I made a workaround for the problem you were having.. on removing the hashes.

So what you can do is set the **Full** Url when you change "locations". For example this:

Lets say you want to go to the login page:

```
window.location.href = "https://mysite/#/login"
```

Now you want to go back to the home page! Then you can do this:

```
window.location.href = "https://mysite/"
```

Comment: Thanks, Chris! With hash = ' ' I can go back too. The problem is the hash character (#) in the url. My home page link is like mysite.com/#

Comment: Yea no problem @ZecaNovaes! Dont forget to mark the question best anwser if it helped you solve the problem to help future users of stackoverflow!

Comment: Sure, thank you! I still trying to find any way to remove this hash in my URL, but your answer can help me too!

Comment: Edit @ZecaNovaes i will anwser that question shortly

Comment: Sorry for the "Chris" name, I couldn't see the "edited by" before haha. I'll edit the post for you!

Comment: @ZecaNovaes Edited my anwser to the solution to your problem. Did it help?

Comment: The problem in change the href is the redirection. I use this hashs to change the page without refreshing, is like an anchor-based site. I'll accept your answer 'cause you are the first person I saw in SO who go back and edit your own answer trying to help. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm @ZecaNovaes im very sorry i cant solve your problem! I just dont seem to work without refreshes. Ill notify you if i get a solution

Comment: No problem! If i get it, I'll post here too! Thank you again!