# Issue on Creating Clean URL Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Can you please let me know how to clean a hashed URL like this

```
domain.com/2.html#box1
```

to

```
domain.com/2.html
```

by removing the `#box1` (the # and everything after that). I already tried this

```
if (location.href.indexOf("#") > -1) {
    location.assign(location.href.replace(/\/?#/, "/"));
}
```

but it generate a URL like

```
domain.com/2.html/box2
```

Comment: `history.replaceState(null, null, "/2.html")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the hash from window.location with JavaScript without page refresh?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397329/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-window-location-with-javascript-without-page-refresh)

Comment: `location.href.replace(/#\w*/, '');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check demo for working example.Bellow regex give all content after #(Containing #) and you just have to replace it with "".

```
a.replace(/#\w*/,"")
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/j386m9ku/3/)