# How to clear window hash without reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a url that user goes to http://www.test.com/test/test#design/test

I want to remove the hash from the url without reloading the page, so that users are now on http://www.test.com/test/test

How can I do that using javascript/jquery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the hash from window.location with JavaScript without page refresh?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397329/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-window-location-with-javascript-without-page-refresh)

Comment: What about window.location.href = 'http://www.test.com/'; ?

Comment: duplicate of this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Answer (score 1):

Try `window.history.pushState('', '/', window.location.pathname);` and fallback to `window.location.hash = ''` if push state is not supported, but this will leave the trailing #.

```
if(window.history.pushState) {
    window.history.pushState('', '/', window.location.pathname)
} else {
    window.location.hash = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
window.history.pushState("","", "#");
```

Comment: You can't do this if you need to support IE 9 or lower
http://caniuse.com/#feat=history