# HTML link to anchor without changing url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button on the top of my page that links to /#tabs (index id="tabs"). it uses a script to scroll nicely down to the id but it changes the url to `www.domain.com/#tabs` how can I remvoe the `#tabs` part? I was thinking about doing it in `.htaccess` but not sure if thats possible and its proerbly a bad idea.

heres the html:

```
    <a class="smoothscroll" href="/#tabs">
      <div class="scroll-down"></div>
    </a>
  </header>

<br />
  <div id="tabs" style="padding:20px;"></div>

  <div class="tabs">
    <h1>About</h1>
    <div class="p">
      about us
      <a href="/contact"><input type="submit" value="Contact Us" class="btn" name="contact" style="min-width:15%;"/></a>
    </div>  
  </div>
```

---

```
<a class="smoothscroll" href="/#tabs">
      <div class="scroll-down"></div>
    </a>
```

Is the button part and it uses this script to scroll smoothly

```
<script>
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
/* Quote Loop
------------------------------------------------------ */

function fade($ele) {
    $ele.fadeIn(1000).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
        var $next = $(this).next('.quote');
        fade($next.length > 0 ? $next : $(this).parent().children().first());
   });
}
fade($('.quoteLoop > .quote').first());


/*----------------------------------------------------*/
/* Smooth Scrolling
------------------------------------------------------ */

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

   $('.smoothscroll').on('click',function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var target = this.hash,
      $target = $(target);

      $('html, body').stop().animate({
          'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
      }, 800, 'swing', function () {
          window.location.hash = target;
      });
  });

});


TweenMax.staggerFrom(".heading", 0.8, {opacity: 0, y: 20, delay: 0.2}, 0.4);
</script>
```

just forget about the top of the script, thats just a part for the index.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5298684/290343

Comment: How about you simply remove the line that _explicitly sets_ the hash after scrolling is done …?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it otherwise like this:

In html

```
<a href="" class="smoothscroll" onclick="functionforscroll('tabs')">
<div class="scroll-down"></div></a>
```

in js

```
var functionforscroll = function(id){
    var reqId = "#"+id;
    window.scrollTo(0, $(reqId).offset().top-85);
}
```

this way you can scroll to the required position without changing the url

Comment: That uses angular, which doesn't seem to be present in the question.

Comment: sry i made changes in pure javascript

Comment: Perfect! Just wanted to make sure that the code would work on their end without any extra inclusions. Nice solution, by the way.

Comment: Add preventdefault / return false to stop the dreaded '#' appearing regardless (or, better yet, use a `<button type='button'` instead of `<a>`)

Comment: thanks freedomn-m and feathercrown for your helpful inputs

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is put a *tabindex="-1"* to the element you want the focus to, and on the event of *focusout/blur* remove that tab index. This will enable the element not to be tabbed, but will bring the focus to the element.

I have done that using JQuery:

```
(ELEMENT_FOR_FOCUS).attr('tabindex', -1).on('blur focusout', function () {
                $(this).removeAttr('tabindex');
            }).focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing Vicky Kumar's answer, this will work.

HTML:

```
<button class="smoothscroll" onclick="functionforscroll('id')">
<div class="scroll-down"></div></button>
```

Javascript

```
const functionforscroll = function(id){
    const reqId = "#"+id;
    window.scrollTo(0, $(reqId).offset().top-85);
}
```

You can style the button to be like the rest of your links in your project.  One thing is to set outline to none, so that when someone clicks the button it will not show the border/outline of the button.

Answer (score 0):

I handle anchor problem by this way without jQuery:

```js
let aWithHref = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="#"]');
aWithHref.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (el.hash) window.scrollTo({
      top: document.querySelector(el.hash).offsetTop
    });
  })
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try use "data-target" instead "href". Works for me.

Comment: Would have been great to provide some basic JS to go with this, as it is this is just a *hint* to go Google something, or rake the OP's code and match it up