# How to remove # from URL in OnePage website

Tags: html, onepage-scroll

I have a one page website which has the following link to a section

```
<a href="#section1">Section 1</a>

<div id="#section1>
TEXT
</div>
```

When I click on the link in the URL it has the #section1 at the end - is it possible to remove this?

The site is hosted on a ngix server

Comment: That URL hash is how the page jumps to a section, you could use JS to remove it after navigating, but I don't believe you can avoid it being added in the first place. (And if you're using JS, you could just use that to do the scrolling without the hash)

Comment: Why do you want to avoid showing the URL you are visiting in the address bar?

Comment: also: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223006/scroll-with-anchor-without-in-url; 2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39596532/html-link-to-anchor-without-changing-url and other numerous duplicate posts !!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using JavaScript but it's not necessary.

```html
<a class="navigate" href="#section-1">Scroll</a>

<script>
document.querySelector('.navigate').forEach(( a ) => {
  a.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    const id = ev.target.id;
    document.getElementById(id).scrollIntoView();
  })
})
```

Here we prevent the default action when clicking the link by using `preventDefault`. Then using JavaScript we get the ID of the element and scroll to the view using JavaScript.

Note that to make that function reusable, we add the class `navigate` to all the anchors that have the same behavior

Comment: duplicate question !!