# How rewrite url in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-routing

I have a single page site. My page has multi section. I define sections with `#`. for example `detail` section has a url like `http://bamap.ir/#/details`.

I want to rout some urls as follow:

- `http://bamap.ir/details` go to `http://bamap.ir/#/details`
- `http://bamap.ir/user-authentication` go to `http://bamap.ir/#/user-authentication`
- ...

How can I rout this urls with `.htacccess`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing the fragment identifier from AngularJS urls (# symbol)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-fragment-identifier-from-angularjs-urls-symbol)

Comment: I'm not using angularjs.

Comment: what are you using then? I think you should detail your question

Comment: [Extjs 6.2.1](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at the History API that HTML5 provides: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#the-history-interface

```
Tfunction removeHash () { 
    var scrollV, scrollH, loc = window.location;
    if ("pushState" in history)
        history.pushState("", document.title, loc.pathname + loc.search);
    else {
        // Prevent scrolling by storing the page's current scroll offset
        scrollV = document.body.scrollTop;
        scrollH = document.body.scrollLeft;

        loc.hash = "";

        // Restore the scroll offset, should be flicker free
        document.body.scrollTop = scrollV;
        document.body.scrollLeft = scrollH;
    }
}
```

quoting the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397329/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-window-location-with-javascript-without-page-refresh)

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting to fregment is imposible as # is not sent to the server. However you could redirect any uri to fregment using the R flag.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^detail/?$ /#/detail [NE,R]
```

This will redirect you to /#/detail if you go to /detail .