# Hide # From Urls Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

after working on an interactive site that automatically navigates using ids in the url, I was wondering how to hide that while it will still navigate normally. After some research on here, I found the following script which doesn't work for me.

```
if ($.browser.msie  && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) === 9 && window.location.href.indexOf("#")) 
    {
        document.location.href = String( document.location.href ).replace( /#/, "" );
    }
```

*ankit Chaudhary & jetpack pony answered my question, I just had concerns that were  dealt with.*

Comment: First, `$.browser` is deprecated for years now, and it's probably already removed from latest `jQuery`s. Second, the code only replaces the `#` mark, but not the hash content itself, which doesn't sound very useful. Please clarify your problem.

Comment: Please specify "doesn't work for me". What exactly does your snippet wrong and what should it do?

Comment: It should hide the id from the url without compromising navigation between those elements with their ids. If I were to enter www.site.com/#home, it will take me to the home section and the url will read www.site.com.

Comment: This will help you  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5298684/290343

Comment: Don't do that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are replacing only "#" symbol in your replace method. To replace the whole hash it should look like this:

```
.replace(/#.+$/, "");
```

Also, instead of `document.location.href` consider using [HTML5 history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API). It provides 2 methods:

**pushState()**: it changes the URL in the URL bar *and creates a new history entry*. For example if you are on a page `example.com/#foo` and you call `history.pushState("", "", "example.com")`, your URL bar will display `example.com` and when you press a browser back arrow, it will take you back to `example.com/#foo`.

**replaceState()**: it changes the URL in the URL bar *and replaces a current history entry*. Meaning that in the same example as above, browser back arrow will take you to a page before `example.com/#foo`.

Here is an example of your code using **pushState()**:

```
var loc = window.location;
if (loc.hash) {
  history.pushState({}, document.title, loc.pathname + loc.search);
}
```

The browser support of this API is very good for details check: [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState()_method) method to manipulate the URL without reloading/refreshing the page.

```
window.history.pushState(
    "object or string", 
    "Title",
    window.location.href.substring(0, window.location.href.indexOf('#'))
);
```

Comment: I'll keep that in mind next time. Can this be used more than once on the same target?