# properly scroll element to the top of the page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, element

What I am trying to do is render my page with a certain element scrolled to the top if the url contains a certain word. I've been able to successfully extract the url with the following:

```
  if(window.location.href.indexOf("Awesome") > -1) {
    alert('hey, your url has Awesome in it!')
  };
```

However I am at a crossroads in terms of getting the page to render with a specific element scrolled to the top... **Any suggestions?**

**UPDATE** - here is my current logic:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){

  (function(){

    function goto(id) {
      var elem = document.getElementById(id);
      window.scrollTo(0, elem.getBoundingClientRect().top);
    }

    if(window.location.href.indexOf("Awesome") > -1) {
      goto('full--stop');
    };
  })();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in two ways :

**1st method:**

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#your element ID").offset().top
}, 2000);
```

**2nd method:**

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>

location.href = "#";
location.href = "#myDiv";
```

Comment: 2nd method was exacting what i sought after, gracias :]

Comment: @JohnJackson glad to know it helps

Comment: would there be anyway to exempt that #myDiv in the actual url? or does that defeat the purpose?

Comment: well you can read the SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397329/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-window-location-with-javascript-without-page-refresh

Comment: i don't believe those answers correlate to my inquiry. I still want the same functionality of scrolling to that element on load, but i want to remove the '#' from the url

Comment: if you don't want # in the url, then follow the first answer.

Comment: it isn't functioning for me

Answer (score 0):

How about getting the position of the element and scrolling there?

```js
function goto(id) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(id);
  window.scrollTo(0, elem.getBoundingClientRect().top);
}
goto('three');
```

```html
<button onclick="goto('two')">Go to two</button>
<button onclick="goto('three')">Go to three</button>
<div id="one">One</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<div id="two">Two</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<div id="three">Three</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
```

More Info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

---

Also if you don't want to do it in JavaScript, then browsers have a built-in feature to scroll to the element with the id that matches the # in the browser URL. So a `example.com/page#myid` would scroll to the element with the id of `myid`.

Comment: the scrollTo solution doesn't seem to work for whatever reason

Comment: @JohnJackson I added a runnable example that works using the same code.

Comment: yes, while this works on a click event, it isn't firing in my 'window.location.href.indexOf("Awesome") > -1' statement, which is called within an IIFE

Comment: I modified the example to go to #three when it loads. Make sure your JavaScript is ran after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: check updated question, i have my code running on a window load event listener, even when i run it in a '$(document).ready(function()' func, no cigar