# Remove #id_popup from URL when click to magnific popup

Tags: jquery, url, modal-dialog, magnific-popup

I use $.magnificPopup.open() with callback method to handle the popup.

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
          type: 'inline',
          preloader: false,
          modal: true,
          items: {
              src: $('#view_detail_popup')
          },
          closeBtnInside: false,
          closeOnBgClick : false,
          enableEscapeKey: false,
          callbacks: {
           //some fucntion here
          }
        });
```

But when I click to button to open the popup. The hashtag **#view_detail_popup** will be add to URL like:

```
localhost/project/items/list_item#view_detail_popup
```

I tried to use

```
$('.view_detail').magnificPopup({
      type: 'inline',
      preloader: false,
      focus: '#view_detail_popup',
      closeBtnInside:true,
      modal: true
    });
```

It didn't add #view_detail_popup to the link but I can't make the callback function for this. So...
My question is: How can I click to open the popup without adding #view_detail_popup to URL?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your JS and add this below code for open a modal pop only:

**Java Script Code:**

```
$(function () {
    $('.popup-modal').magnificPopup({
        type: 'inline',
        preloader: false,
        focus: '#username',
        modal: true
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.popup-modal-dismiss', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.magnificPopup.close();
    });
});
```

**HTML Code**

```
<a class="popup-modal" href="#test-modal">Open modal</a>

<div id="test-modal" class="white-popup-block mfp-hide">
    <h1>Modal dialog</h1>
    <p>You won't be able to dismiss this by usual means (escape or
        click button), but you can close it programatically based on
        user choices or actions.</p>
    <p><a class="popup-modal-dismiss" href="#">Dismiss</a></p>
</div>
```

Try with this one.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to overwrite what you've done. You can use the [HTML5 History API](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#the-history-interface) and [magnific popup's callback option](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#events) to run a function that clears the URL while opening or closing the popup:

```
$('.popup-modal').magnificPopup({
  callbacks: {

    open: function() {
      history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);
    } // over-write URL when popup is opened

    close: function() {
      history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);
    } // over-write URL when popup is closed
  }
})
```

For the above question I'd go with the `open: function` only.

This works in Chrome 9, Firefox 4, Safari 5, Opera 11.50 and in IE 10. For unsupported browsers, you could always write a gracefully degrading script that makes use of it where available ¯\_(シ)_/¯
Something like this: [How to remove the hash from window.location (URL) with JavaScript without page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397329/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-window-location-url-with-javascript-without-page-r/5298684#5298684)