# Top anchor with smooth scroll that won't repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 1000, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = none;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
```

I'm running this to smooth scroll to "#top" without changing the url-hash. I accidentally discovered a way to modify this so that the URL won't update (added "none" for the "window.location.hash"), but there's one problem; Now the function won't repeat.

**Here's what happens:**

- Load page
- Scroll down
- Press top anchor
- Page scrolls to top (without updating url)
- Scroll down again
- Press top anchor
- Nothing happens

Don't know where I got this snippet, but I've had it in my js-folder for a while.

Comment: `window.location.hash = none;` - if you look in your browser console, you're getting "`none` is not defined." If you want to keep the URL from having an empty hash if you click on a `<a href="#">top</a>` link, add `id="top"` to `body` or your first/top element or whatever, and change that link to `<a href="#top">top</a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing two ways to scroll the page.

`hash` is the `#something` in the URL... Usefull to scroll to an anchor on page load.

See the `#hello` effect in this link: https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/ybWNbJ?editors=1111#hello

Then, for the user to scroll to the top of the page, I would use the `id` of the top anchor in the `href` of the link which triggers the scroll function.
This would trigger the function on this specific link instead of ALL links in the page. ;)

And finally, this line: `window.location.hash = none;` is trying to chang the original onload hash value to `none` which is interpreted as an undefined variable since this is expecting a string.

> ReferenceError: none is not defined

I would simply remove that line...
or if you really want to clear the hash value:

```
window.location.hash = "";
```

Working scroll top function: *See codePen for the HTML markup changed)*

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a#backTOtop").on('click', function(event) {
    console.log($(this).attr("href"));

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if ($(this).href !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var top = $(this).attr("href");

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(top).offset().top
      }, 1000, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        // window.location.hash = none;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Excellent explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

If you not need to affect the url hash, just remove (or comment with //) that line of code; because it generate error in javascript.

If you want to remove the hash from url, try this code:

```
history.pushState('', document.title, window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
```

- Source: [How to remove the hash from window.location with JavaScript without page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397329/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-window-location-with-javascript-without-page-refresh/5298684#5298684)

Comment: I don't get how it is usefull. Just NO CODE about the hash would be okay. What you suggest is replacing the hash value A with value A. Useless.