# link to remove `#` from url without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, html, url, anchor, single-page-application

I have this sample html page called `pound.html`

```
<body onload="alert('loading')">
  <a href="#something">something after #</a><br />
  <a href="#">nothing after #</a><br />
  <a href="">no # at all</a><br >
</body>
```

I have added in an alert so that I can tell when the page reloads.

If I click on the first link, the url changes to `pound.html#something` as expected.  If I click on the second link, it changes to `pound.html#`, again without reloaded.  But If I click on the third link, while it puts the url back to `pound.html` (no `#`) it reloads the page.

I always see single page apps where you have no `#` when you start up, but once you have gone somewhere else, and then returned to the home page, you are left with `#`.  Is there a way to make it remove the `#` from the url without reloading the page (like when you go back to the homepage)?

---

If you start on `pound.html`, and then click on the first link and get to `pound.html#something`, the browser back arrow can get you back to `pound.html` without reloading the page.

As mentioned in the comments, there are lots of javascript solutions here [How to remove the hash from window.location (URL) with JavaScript without page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397329/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-window-location-url-with-javascript-without-page-r)

However, does anybody know if there is a way to remove to make a link do that?

Comment: Try here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397329/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-window-location-url-with-javascript-without-page-r

Comment: thanks - will edit question

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```js
window.location.hash = '1' // add the `#1` to URL (adds hash if its not already there)
window.location.hash = '' // just leave the `#` symbol in URL
window.history.replaceState(null,document.title,location.href.slice(0, -1))
```

It'll remove the last character from your URL (in this case, a `#`)