# htaccess get rid of # in address bar

Tags: .htaccess

I have a dropdown menu item as below but it shows in the address bar as: index.php#!

How can I rid of the "#!" ?

```
    <li><a href="#!">About</a>
     
     <ul class="nav-dropdown">
     <li ><a href="bio.php">Biography</a></li>
     <li ><a href="master.php">in the news</a></li>
     </ul>
     
     </li>
```

Comment: That cannot be done in .htaccess because `#` and fragment after that is not even sent to web server.

Comment: What about a javascript solution,,,?

Comment: please check: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1397329/548225

Comment: That is a useful answer. Thanks!