# How to remove the "#" symbol from the URL

Tags: javascript, html

I have a link that takes me to another section of the same page like this:

```html
<a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
```

that takes me here:

```html
<section class="page-section bg-primary" id="about"></section>
```

Whenever I click on the link, the search bar shows up as `http://mywebsite.com/home/#about`. I want it so that whenever an anchor link is clicked it takes me to that section in the page but instead of having a hash in the search bar I want it nice and clean with `/` instead of `#`, like `http://mywebsite.com/home/about`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: This is the default behavior of html5, you can't change it, `#` indicates id of any element, the thing you want  i.e. clean urls, you can achieve that through django's urls.

Comment: yeah but i don't know how to move from one section to another from the same page using django

Comment: You cannot move in the page using routes, so this is the default behavior. It can be done if you create another page for about section.

Comment: yeah i figured thank you, i spent the whole day searching and now im just gonna make each section in an HTML file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the hash from window.location (URL) with JavaScript without page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397329/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-window-location-url-with-javascript-without-page-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *may* be done using a [`popstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event) event handler and [`history.replaceState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState).

Not sure if this is necessarily the best or even a viable solution.

```
window.addEventListener(`popstate`, handle);

function handle(evt) {
  if (location.hash) {
    history.replaceState(null, ``, location.pathname);
  }
}
```

It can't be demonstrated in a snippet here, so check [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-55dcjf?file=script.js).

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:
`location.origin+location.pathname`.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the hash change and replace the search bar's `#` with a `/`.

Here's some (independent) code:

```js
let first = true; // so we know whether to replace or add
window.addEventListener("hashchange", () => {
    if(first)
        return (
            history.pushState(null, null, location.href.replace("#", "/")),
            first = false
        );
    const all = location.href.split("/"); // if we replaced the last one with `/`, we don't want to add on to it
    all[all.length - 1] = location.hash.slice(1); // slice(1) gets rid of the `#`
    history.pushState(null, null, all.join("/"));
});
```

This exhibits all the normal traits of an anchor link, where when you click on a link the page's history is pushed instead of replaced. I think this is also what you wanted from what I could understand in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is part of HTML. In my opinion is that good to have hash routes. But i dont know your issue. How ever. A simple solution would be to listen to the anchors and remove the `#` after clicking.

```js
const anchors = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link");
anchors.forEach(a => {
  a.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("remove # from: ", window.location.href)
    window.location.href.split('#')[0]
    return false;
  })
})
```