# How to return an empty pushState (or clear the current state) when fetching the index page

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch-api, tumblr, html5-history

I am trying to turn a Tumblr site into a single page application.

Currently my page links work, I parse the `href` attribute for each link, fetch the corresponding page, then update the `pushState` as well as an additional `popstate` event listener so I can pass this to the history object.

The issue arises if I am on a specific sub page (about, contact etc) and then navigate to the index, the `pushState` is not replaced, even though for the index I am passing an empty string.

This seems like a pretty fundamental issue that I am assuming lots of JS libraries have resolved (React, Vue etc).

Here is my slightly truncated JS:

```
let internal = [...links].filter(item => item.getAttribute('href').startsWith('/'));

const updateContent = (input) => {
    pageWrapper.replaceChildren();
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(input, 'text/html');
    const container = doc.querySelector('#container');
    pageWrapper.appendChild(container);
}

internal.forEach(item => {
    let href = item.getAttribute('href');
    let hrefSplit = href.split('/')[1];
    item.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        body.classList.add(loadingClass);
        if (href === '/') {
            hrefSplit = "";
        } 
        fetch(href)
            .then((res) => {
                return res.text();
            })
            .then((html) => {
                updateContent(html);
                history.pushState({ path: href }, "", hrefSplit); // does not work when the href is just '/'
                body.classList.remove(loadingClass);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
                body.classList.remove(loadingClass);
            });
    });

    document.addEventListener('popstate', (event) => {
        const state = event.originalEvent.state;
        if (state) {
            updateContent(state.path);
        }
    });
});
```

My only thought it that perhaps an empty string won't ever work, or if the fetch url is the index page, you have to manually remove the previous `pushState`, but not 100% sure.

I can add more code here if needed, but in addition all the code can be accessed at the Tumblr URL (it is slightly more verbose but the core functionality should be the same):
https://malarkey-test.tumblr.com/

Comment: Lol, I tried snooping for slightly different search terms in google and stumbled on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397329/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-window-location-url-with-javascript-without-page-r I can just do `history.pushState({ path: href }, "", "/");` which is hilariously simple. I could provide an answer but it seems like I found out just by googling, so I am also happy if a mod wants to close this question.