# how facebook controls #! in url

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, fragment-identifier, browser-state

how can i controls #! in url suppose i have the following url

`http://www.facebook.com/#!/video/video.php?v=1106030301789`

now how facebook controls that `#!` in url....

Comment: should be tagged: "location.hash"

Comment: @meleyal That tag does not exist. I file this topic under [fragment-identifier], since the only other option, [hash], is hopelessly overloaded.

Comment: i tried to add the tag, but don't have enough rep :(

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/browser-state

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the shebang (#!) in Facebook URLs for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-in-facebook-urls-for)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html - this might explain a little about it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [sammy.js](http://code.quirkey.com/sammy/)

```
$.sammy(function() {

  this.get('#/', function() {
    $('#main').text('Welcome!');
  });

});
```

Or [route.js](http://maraksquires.com/route.js/)

```
route('#/Learn').bind(function(){ 
    Alert('Alert1'); 
});
```

There's also a standards way to do it with [the new popstate event in html5](http://www.spoiledmilk.dk/blog/?p=1922)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: via Ajax

Ajax allows main page to dynamically load content without need to refresh page

Comment: If the URL in the address bar is changing, it's not Ajax.

Comment: The URL is changed in the normal way, with links changing the anchor/hash. An event listener sees the change and calls the ajax.