# What does this untypical link format '#!' means?

Tags: url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the shebang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for)

Hello,

One thing that took my attention in some modern websites is the presence of '**#!**' symbols in their links, see for example twitter and Rapidshare links:

```
http://twitter.com/#!/SolidSnakeGTI
http://twitter.com/#!/SolidSnakeGTI/followers
http://twitter.com/#!/SolidSnakeGTI/following
This behavior is obvious when you're logged in twitter

http://rs431tl3.rapidshare.com/#!download|46311|44541812469|fairy_tgail_045_sd.mp4
```

What does these symbols mean, what it's called, how it works!?

Appreciated in advance
Abdelrahman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about [making AJAX applications crawlable](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html).