# #! In a URL, what does it mean?

Tags: web-services, security, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the shebang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for)

`#!` What does it mean in a URL ?
I found it in facebook & twitter url !

`http://www.facebook.com/#!/`
`http://www.facebook.com/#!/?sk=messages`
`http://www.facebook.com/#!/?sk=ff&ap=1`

`http://twitter.com/#!/messages`
`http://twitter.com/#!/BillGates`

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935250/what-does-this-untypical-link-format-means which duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-in-facebook-urls-for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called the **shebang** URL hash, used to hint to search engines that this site is using Ajax to display another page.

Answer (score 2):

It is meant for [AJAX and Google indexing](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html).