# What is the purpose of #! in an url

Tags: url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the shebang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for)

This question may have been asked before so bear with me. #! (pound exclamation) is not a great search term neither on this site nor on google.

So anyway, I'm noticing a lot of facebook urls with these two characters in them. What is it used for?

Comment: I've seen an answer to this here on SO... can't find it now though.

Comment: #! is usually called _shebang_. This helps a lot when searching about it! You can check this question, as it's an exact duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for

Comment: How can this both be offtopic and be an exact duplicate of a question with over 100 upvotes?

Comment: @Vincent, yep. That's the question I was looking for :-)

Comment: Thanks everyone. I thought I had seen that question before too but I obviously failed to search for *shebang*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should explain it:

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html

It boils down to making AJAX-sites crawlable.

Update: And from [the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for/3009501#3009501): http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/

Comment: As of October 14, 2015, Google has deprecated the technique: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html