# Why do many sites using "#!/" for AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the shebang/hashbang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for)

Many Ajax sites use `#!/` in their URLs. Examples include Twitter (https://twitter.com/#!/Linksku) and Grooveshark (http://grooveshark.com/#!/).

Why do they use the exclamation mark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4175129/1232478 links to two Google items that explain it pretty well. In short, it helps make AJAX sites crawlable.

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html

is ultimately the link.