# What does the (#!) in Twitter URLs do?

Tags: html, css, url, twitter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the shebang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for)

What does the (#!) in Twitter URLs do?

Example: http://twitter.com/#!/search/stackoverflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a way to make ajax applications crawlable. Check this out:

- [Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/specification.html)

Answer (score 4):

Its for search bots:
http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html

Answer (score 1):

It's called a shebang or hashbang, besides the above mentioned (making Ajax actions crawable). It does, in a more general sense, make Ajax actions and results more accessible, for example, at Facebook. For example the URL http://twitter.com/#!/search/stackoverflow redirects to http://twitter.com/search/stackoverflow - so you can just give it to someone and that person sees the same as you did after invoking some Ajax functionality. Facebook does the same with picture galleries.