# What does /#!/ mean in URL?

Tags: php, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the shebang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for)

It usually comes straight after the domain name.

I see it all the time, like in Twitter and Facebook urls.

Is it some special sort of routing?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184666/what-does-the-in-twitter-urls-do and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for

Answer (score 6, accepted):

after `#` is the hash of the location; the `!` the follows is used by search engines to help index ajax content. After that can be anything, but is usually rendered to look as a path (hence the `/`). If you want to know more, read [this](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html).

Answer (score 17):

`#` is the fragment separator. Everything before it is handled by the server, and everything after it is handled by the client, usually in JavaScript (although it will advance the page to an anchor with the same name as the fragment).