# Url being trimmed if # is present

Tags: php

I have read this: [What does /#!/ mean in URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238799/what-does-mean-in-url) and so I'm aware # is a fragment separator, but I am having difficulties with $_GET ing a URL to display on a subsequent page, where the # is present.

I have a php page which sends a user input, a URL, to another page where it is displayed.

```
<?php echo $_GET["url"]; ?>
```

Where the url containing the variables looks like this...

```
http://website.com/qr/index.php?url=http://www.example.com&many=false&set=false
```

http://www.example.com is displayed.

Whereas a url containing a fragment like this...

```
http://website.com/qr/index.php?url=http://www.example.com/#fragment&many=false&set=false
```

displays nothing.

I am not able to use $_POST.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Actually, `$_GET['url']` should be filled in both situations, because the `#` is after the url parameter. You would not be able to read `$_GET['many']` and `$_GET['set']` in the second case, because it's part of the fragment (which is not sent to the server afaik), but `$_GET['url']` should be fine. So I think the error shoul be somewhere else.

Comment: If you're passing `#` as part of the value of a parameter, you have to URLEncode it first. Can't just leave it as `#` because then its treated as part of this url rather than part of the parameter value.

Comment: Everything behind an non-encoded `#` is never sent to the server

Answer (score 4):

You should probably [URL encode](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm) the parameter you are placing in the URL , especially since it also is a URL (meaning it has a very high likelihood of containing characters that have a special meaning in the context of a URL, such as `#` and `/`).  If you're using Javascript to put the URL parameter in you can do this with [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).  If you're using PHP to add that URL parameter, it is [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

From that first link, the pound sign falls under the "Unsafe characters" category which garner from the author this further advice (emphasis mine):

> Some characters present the possibility of being misunderstood within URLs for various reasons. *These characters should also always be encoded*.

That "Unsafe" designation comes from [RFC 1738](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) which has this to say about the Pound Character specifically (again, emphasis mine):

> All unsafe characters must always be encoded within a URL. For
>      example, the character "#" must be encoded within URLs *even in
>      systems that do not normally deal with fragment or anchor
>      identifiers*, so that if the URL is copied into another system that
>      does use them, it will not be necessary to change the URL encoding.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) or [rawurlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php). Otherwise all after the '#' is part of the fragment and its possible that you get some problems.