# Why exclamation is used in URLs?

Tags: url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the shebang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for)

Hi

I was just wondering what is the use of "!" in urls like this

`http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=xxxxxxxx&v=wall#!/profile.php?id=yyyyyy&v=wall`

I know Facebook uses **#**(hash) for changing the query string parameters with JavaScript but what is the meaning of exclamation (**!**), why it is used after # ? We can even work with # only to change the querystring params. Is there any benefit of using ! ? or any other thing is there which I am missing ?

Comment: Take a look at this related SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because it is an [AJAX crawlable notation for URLS](http://ajaxian.com/archives/proposal-for-customizing-google-crawlable-ajax-urls), an [effort driven by Google to define a convention allowing Web 2.0 websites to be indexed by search engines](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/).

And of course check the perfectly valid answer for [What's the Shebang in the new Facebook and Twitter URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for)

Answer (score 3):

It's a convention used for AJAX requests, [one that lets google crawl that ajax content](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html). There are some other major examples of this, twitter for example.

In Chrome (and other browsers as they support it) you won't see those URLs, since facebook is *also* using some HTML5 history features to change the URL in the address bar/browser history.