# What does #! mean prior to path in Php script?

Tags: php

Trying to learn PHP and a more experienced dev made a number of modifications to my PHP script but I did not get an opp to ask what does the "#!" next to the path in my PHP script?  This sits at the very top of the PHP file that I was working on:

#!/opt/local/bin/php

Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: [Why exclamation is used in URLs? [closed]][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376719/why-exclamation-is-used-in-urls

Comment: That is not PHP, it's a shell command for linux systems. I'm guessing that is for CLI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a way to tell Linux to run the script code using the application at `/opt/local/bin/php`. If you were running PHP as a plugin to apache, you'd use the `<?php ?>` tags to identify PHP code.

Comment: The `<?php ?>` tags to identify PHP code are required by a "standalone" interpreter as well. Anything not enclosed by them is directed to STDOUT.

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia explains it fairly simple: [Shebang (unix)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)

> Under Unix-like operating systems, when a script with a shebang is run
>   as a program, the program loader parses the rest of the script's
>   initial line as an interpreter directive; the specified interpreter
>   program is run instead, passing to it as an argument the path that was
>   initially used when attempting to run the script.[11] For example, if
>   a script is named with the path "path/to/script", and it starts with
>   the following line:
>
> `#!/bin/sh`
>
> then the program loader is instructed to run the program "/bin/sh"
>   instead (usually this is the Bourne shell or a compatible shell),
>   passing "path/to/script" as the first argument.
>   The shebang line is usually ignored by the interpreter because the "#"
>   character is a comment marker in many scripting languages; some
>   language interpreters that do not use the hash mark to begin comments
>   (such as Scheme) still may ignore the shebang line in recognition of
>   its purpose.[12]

Answer (score 2):

It's called a Shebang see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)

> Under Unix-like operating systems, when a script with a shebang is run
>   as a program, the program loader parses the rest of the script's
>   initial line as an interpreter directive; the specified interpreter
>   program is run instead, passing to it as an argument the path that was
>   initially used when attempting to run the script.[11]