# Gmail Kind Of Page Load

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, twitter, gmail

While working with Gmail the URLs seem to be like https://mail.google.com/mail/?shva=1#inbox. I observed that there is # symbol in URLs. Also Facebook, Twitter will load page content in the similar way without loading entire page it just refreshes required block.

What kind of concept / technology they are using. 
Can we do so using JQuery? 
Will search engines can crawl page content in those scenarios?

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for

Answer (score 2):

A jQuery framework that does this is the jQuery.history plugin. It is indeed used (as the comment of marcgg states) by means of AJAX. A tutorial for this can be found here, in its most simple form:

http://www.queness.com/post/328/a-simple-ajax-driven-website-with-jqueryphp

Answer (score 1):

> Can we do so using JQuery?

[Yes](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/).

> Will search engines can crawl page
>   content in those scenarios?

Check @marcgg comment!