# Google is indexing a jquery loaded page, but not the parent page

Tags: jquery, load, indexing

we have a html page (out_of_stock.html) that is using jquery to load a php page. were are using the the load function from jquery as follows :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#phpcontent').load('/outofstock.php');
});
```

the problem is that google is indexing the page outofstock.php instead of the page out_of_stock.html. is there anyway to have google index the page out_of_stock.html with all the content of outofstock.php in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this url: http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/

Also [here is a SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for) explaining the concept.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the URL hash technique.

See: http://www.techwyse.com/blog/search-engine-optimization/let-google-crawl-your-ajax-based-content/