# Why does Twitter use a hash and exclamation mark in URLs, and how do they rewrite search URLs?

Tags: ajax, twitter, fragment-identifier

We understand the hash is for AJAX searches, but the exclamation mark?  Anyone know?

Also, the "action" attribute for their search form points to "/search," but when you conduct a search, the hash exclamation mark appears in the URL.  Are they simply redirecting from "/search" to "/#!/search"?

**Note:** the second part of the q remains unanswered: That is, are they redirecting the user from "/search" to "/#!/search", or do they send the user to "/search" and use JS on the page to rewrite the URL? – Crashalot Jan 26 at 23:51

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the shebang/hashbang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for) - at least the first part anyway

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer the second part then: It is redirecting you to /#!/search.

If you look at the response headers when going to http://twitter.com/britishdev (plug plug) you are returned a 302 (temporary redirect) with the Location header set as "Location: http://twitter.com/#!/britishdev"

Yes JavaScript is then pulling all your detail in on the destination page but regardless that is where you are redirected to.

Comment: ha ha. ah you love a sense of humour!

Comment: fyi i didn't downvote, i just figured whoever did it was because of that. it made me chuckle :)

Answer (score 31):

It's become the de facto standard that Google has established to ensure consistency and make ajax urls crawlable.

See http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html

I believe they are using `history.pushState`. You can do `history.back()` in the console and it'll lead you back to the page.

Comment: Actually, I realized the second part of the question remains unanswered.  That is, are they redirecting the user from "/search" to "/#!/search", or do they send the user to "/search" and use JS on the page to rewrite the URL?

Answer (score 23):

Yes, it redirects with HTTP 302.

By the way, "!" is used to eliminate the case with an empty hash. "http://url#" will make a browser to slide to the top.

Comment: And also for this

http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html