# ! in url hash design

Tags: javascript, url, asynchronous, routes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Twitter use a hash and exclamation mark in URLs, and how do they rewrite search URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739667/why-does-twitter-use-a-hash-and-exclamation-mark-in-urls-and-how-do-they-rewrit)

While working with hashy routes for async websites, I've seen sites use a leading exclamation point, like the following: `#!/some/route`

What is benefit of including an exclamation point directly after a hash? Does it signify something?

Comment: Though similar, I can't really say its a real duplicate, because its asking two separate questions, and the selected answer talks specifically about a redirect to twitter's search url... so I'm looking for something a bit more general than what twitter did for one particular page. I do see it in a lot of places

Comment: See the second answer for that question. Basically, because google's search bots expect it that way if you want ajax "pages" to be indexed.