# What kind of technique is used behind: "http://abcde.com/#!download|"?

Tags: javascript, ajax, url

i've seen URLs like this
    https://rapidshare.com/#!download|
and that
    http://www.facebook.de/#!xyz
several times on the web. It looks like cutting-edge ajax (i'm not a JavaScript guy), but it's not easy to find tutorials on this. My Question is: How is this technique called and where can I find more on that ? By the way, even the (good) wikipedia article for "ajax" has absolutly no information on that. Thanks, crowd !

Comment: google for `hashbang` / `shebang`

Comment: possible duplicate of [! in url hash design](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146165/in-url-hash-design)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is this technique called

Hashbang. [I asked about this a while back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146165/in-url-hash-design).

When you use the hash by itself, its just triggering the hash change event in newer browsers. Using a hash change event works well with modern JS style applications (node style frameworks) because its all asynchronous. The problem is that those pages don't get indexed by google.

However, it was discovered that if you prefix the hash content with `!`, it *does* get indexed by google. Awesome!

> where can I find more on that ?

For more, read this: http://mtrpcic.net/2011/02/fragment-uris-theyre-not-as-bad-as-you-think-really/

Answer (score 4):

The `#!` syntax is a way to tell the google bot that the resource is also available with a regular HTTP request when removing the hashbang and appending the url behind the `!` to the path (if it's absolute, after removing the old path).